# different ways to grep for two distinct strings, appearing in any order, or line, in the same file

Tags: bash, grep

I want to return all files that have the strings: `"main("` as well as `"foo"`.

This is like using a multi pattern OR grep but with AND instead.

The best I've come up with is:

```
grep -rl . -e "main("|while read fname; do grep -rl "$fname" -e "foo"; done
```

It does the job, but ideally I wouldn't have to write bash script.

E.g.

text1.txt:

```
int main()
{
    stuff....
}

foo
```

grep command would return text1.txt since it contains the strings 'main(' and 'foo'

Comment: Some example input/output would be useful. Please [edit] the question to add some.

Comment: If * could match everything (including new lines) then the following could also work:

grep -E -r 'main(.*foo(' ./*

Comment: Can be either the same line or different lines

Comment: @LukePurnell: Something like this should work `awk '/main\(/ && /foo/{print FILENAME}' * 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
grep -rlZ 'main(' | xargs -0 grep -l 'foo'
```

> -Z, --null
>                 Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character  that  normally  follows  a  file
>                 name.   For  example,  grep  -lZ outputs a zero byte after each file name instead of the usual newline.
>                 This option makes the output unambiguous, even  in  the  presence  of  file  names  containing  unusual
>                 characters  like  newlines.  This option can be used with commands like find -print0, perl -0, sort -z,
>                 and **xargs -0** to process arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.

The first `grep` would print all filenames containing `main(` separated by NUL character. `xargs` would then pass the files to second `grep` command which would print files containing `foo`

If the files are small enough and do not contain NUL character,

```
grep -rlz 'main(.*foo\|foo.*main('
```

where `-z` would use NUL as line separator, effectively slurping whole file

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk to match both patterns and print filenames:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { m = f = 0 }         # reset flags at start of each file
     /main\(/ { ++m } /foo/ { ++f } # set flags when patterns match
     m && f { print FILENAME; nextfile }' **/*
```

`nextfile` is a GNU extension which skips to the next file, rather than the next line. With `globstar` enabled, `**` expands recursively. In an interactive bash shell, it is enabled by default, but in a script you can enable it yourself using `shopt -s globstar`.

With non-GNU awk, you can use another flag to skip lines and avoid printing the filename multiple times:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { m = f = p = 0 } # reset flags at start of each file
     p { next }                 # skip lines once this filename has been printed
     /main\(/ { ++m } /foo/ { ++f } 
     m && f { print FILENAME; ++p }' **/*
```

Comment: Good to know about `nextfile` but any idea why the flags `m` and `f` are needed? just the AND on both the pattern matches wouldn't suffice?

Comment: The flags mean that the matches can be on different lines in the file.

Comment: This seems less intuitive to me than my grep and bash script solution! "Just use awk..." followed by huge awk command!

Comment: It's only "huge" because I added a load of of spaces and comments. It can be made more compact, though arguably at the expense of readability.